# How to make Meteor + Geth working together?

Tags: go-ethereum, meteor

I want to integrate a server side web server with a blockchain as a distributed database.
What patterns are available to do so?

Comment: This was flagged by a user who said: "I think this is probably a good answer, it's just a question right now. Might you be able to move stuff around?"

Comment: @eth, not sure what you mean by moving stuff around. Any idea for improving the design?

Comment: Maybe try writing a question, and posting the explanation as an answer.

Comment: Ok. question edited and answer posted. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

After several days of research on the above components, I have finally been able to make it work.
I want to share my researches so others can benefit and contribute.
I profit of this message to thanks you all for the posts that has helped me understand the pieces.

My design was to have a server (Meteor) to server (Geth) communication and not a browser to geth communication as I consider Geth should be in the DMZ of the company and the application is intranet type so inside the company network.

1. The architecture I have studied
   [image: Development setup]
2. The initialisation of the web3 component 
   [image: Interaction diagram for the web3 initialisation on server side]
   To be noted here that I still have a problem where the ethereum:web3 library does not recognize correctly the XMLHttpRequest and XHR2 libs and therefore had to tweek the ethereum_web3.js. Advise on how to fix this are welcome.
3. The construction of a reactive subscription on a Contract to be used in web browser template
   [image: Interaction diagram for all layers between the browser to Geth]

I can comment further upon questions.

Good luck for all who are experimenting.